# How to remove only the matching string part

Tags: regex, sed

I need to remove `[PR:]` from the `[PR:Parker]` which only print "`ParkerS`"

Note:[PR:xxxxxxx] "xxxxxxx" Part is changed time to time.

Upto now I have create a following sed command:

```
sed 's/[PR:]//g' | sed 's/[][]//g'
```

But it prints "`arkerS`" which missing the "`P`" in name too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/\[PR:\([^][]*\)]/\1/' <<< "[PR:Parker]"
```

Here, the `\[PR:\([^][]*\)]` matches `[PR:`, then any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` are captured into Group 1 and a `]` is matched, and the match is replaced with the Group 1 value (with `\1` placeholder).

Or,

```sh
sed -E 's/\[PR:|]//g' <<< "[PR:Parker]"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/kiRwA9). Here, `\[PR:|]` matches either `[PR:` or `]` and the `s` command removes them.

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With `awk`, with your shown samples, please try following code once. Using `gsub` function to globally substituting starting `[` followed by `PR:` and `]` ending with NULL and printing rest of the values of line.

```
awk '{gsub(/^\[PR:|\]$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using different field separator(s) in `awk` code to grab 2nd last value as per shown samples, try following.

```
awk -F':|\\]' '{print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk` try following. Matching regex `/:[^]]*/` from 1st occurrence of `:` to before `]` occurs and printing the matched part only as per requirement.

```
awk 'match($0,/:[^]]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

***4th solution:*** Using bash capability of parameter expansion here. In case you have this value in a shell variable then this will be BEST solution to go for.

```
##If your shown sample is in a shell variable, use parameter expansion then.
var="[PR:Parker]"

##Create interim variable var1 to remove everything from starting till : here.
var1="${var##*:}"
echo "$var1"
Parker]

##Then on var1 remove ] and get needed value here.
echo "${var1%*]}"
Parker
```

***5th solution:*** Using `perl` one liner try following, performing global substitution to remove starting `[PR:` and ending `]` with null.

```
perl -pe 's/^\[PR:|\]$//g' Input_file
```